# Change categories url in OpenCart version 3.0.3.7

Tags: opencart

I would like to change the urls for the categories. On my page, there are 4 categories: Home,Shop,About,Contact. For example, when I hit "Home", I want it to load the home page. Is there anyway to do that on OpenCart?

Edit:

This is the meu.twig:

```
{% if categories %}
<div class="container">
  <nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">{{ text_category }}</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        {% for category in categories %}
        {% if category.children %}
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="{{ category.href }}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category.name }}</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner"> {% for children in category.children|batch(category.children|length / category.column|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                {% for child in children %}
                <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endfor %}</div>
            <a href="{{ category.href }}" class="see-all">{{ text_all }} {{ category.name }}</a> </div>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: which themes are used? tell me a full description about your website

Comment: Hi, I am using the Default Store Theme. The only things that I changed are removing the carousel and also editing the categories to Home,Shop,About,Contact .

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\op_3037\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\menu.twig

Comment: check this one and reply me

Comment: Hi, I added the menu.twig.

Comment: please upload with screenshot or URL. for a better understanding of all developers

Comment: Apologies. Here is the current site: http://cuppela.com/

Comment: here nothing to show opencart website

Comment: Hi, is the link broken? It seems fine when I click it.

Comment: you have installed the extension. default menu comes to menu.twig and it's the only category. not Home, Shop, About, and Contact

Comment: you can see that :https://demo.opencart.com/

Comment: It does only show Home, Shop, About and Contact on this page: http://cuppela.com/index.php?route=common/home .

Comment: Hi, can I solve it without giving admin access as it is a private site?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235446/discussion-between-nkm-and-mujahid-bhoraniya).